# Как сделать хорошо построенный текст по примеру Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Всё почти сделал но ломаю голову над одним, к делу

У меня есть вот такой код:

```
        operations = func.operations()
        #Getting data
        final_str = ''
        for opertime in operations:
            regtime1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(opertime[1]))
            formatedate1 = regtime1.strftime("%m.%d.%Y")
            formatetime1 = regtime1.strftime("%H:%M")
            
            final_str += '\n'+formatetime1 + ' - ' + opertime[0]
```

В нем, программа получает из бд 2 столбца в котором (operation, time). В первом какая операция была и во втором время операции. Я хочу сделать сделать всё в вот таком виде:

```
- Дата: 02.05.2022

16:02 - Покупка шампуня

15:58 - Покупка утюга

12:13 - Покупка подписки

10:25 - Покупка карты

- Дата: 01.05.2022

22:20 - Покупка подписки

17:05 - Покупка бытовой техники

16:59 - Покупка мяса

16:58 - Покупка фена
```

Как вы видите дата не повторяется возле каждой новой строки, а только в том случае если наступил новый день, как это возможно сделать более менее нормально, жду ваши варианты!

Comment: Приведите пример `operations`

Comment: Покупка мяса 1650456884
Покупка техники 1650463121
Покупка машины 1650463177
Покупка кольца 1650463544
Покупка листа А4 1650482406
Покупка товара 1650523818
Покупка подписки 1650525954
Покупка фена 1650532411
Покупка люстры 1650545934

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если операции сгруппировать по дате, то проблем вывести не будет

Пример:

```
import datetime as DT
from collections import defaultdict


operations = [
    ('Покупка мяса', 1650456884),
    ('Покупка техники', 1650463121),
    ('Покупка машины', 1650463177),
    ('Покупка кольца', 1650463544),
    ('Покупка листа А4', 1650482406),
    ('Покупка товара', 1650523818),
    ('Покупка подписки', 1650525954),
    ('Покупка фена', 1650532411),
    ('Покупка люстры', 1650545934),
]

date_by_operations = defaultdict(list)
for name, timestamp in operations:
    regtime = DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    date_by_operations[regtime.date()].append(
        (regtime.time(), name)
    )

for date, ops in date_by_operations.items():
    print(f'- Дата: {date:%d.%m.%Y}')

    for time, name in ops:
        print(f'{time:%H:%M} - {name}')

    print()
```

Результат:

```
- Дата: 20.04.2022
17:14 - Покупка мяса
18:58 - Покупка техники
18:59 - Покупка машины
19:05 - Покупка кольца

- Дата: 21.04.2022
00:20 - Покупка листа А4
11:50 - Покупка товара
12:25 - Покупка подписки
14:13 - Покупка фена
17:58 - Покупка люстры
```

Comment: for name, timestamp in operations:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) , это может быть из-за того что есть первая колонка с нумерацией 1,2,3,4?

Comment: В общем всё работает, спасибо большое

Comment: @Kowl, да, у вас в `operations` было больше подэлементов в элементах :) Можно так вытаскивать `for _, name, timestamp in operations:`, если элемент не важен, а если у вас таких подэлементов больше, тогда можно проигнорировать все, кроме явно указанных: `for _, name, timestamp, *_ in operations:`

Comment: @Kowl, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2):

для группировки можно воспользоваться itertools:

```
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import groupby

operations = [
    ('Покупка мяса', 1650456884),
    ('Покупка техники', 1650463121),
    ('Покупка машины', 1650463177),
    ('Покупка кольца', 1650463544),
    ('Покупка листа А4', 1650482406),
    ('Покупка товара', 1650523818),
    ('Покупка подписки', 1650525954),
    ('Покупка фена', 1650532411),
    ('Покупка люстры', 1650545934)]

op = map(lambda x: (x[0], datetime.fromtimestamp(x[1])), operations)

for d, g in groupby(op, lambda x: x[1].date()):
    print(f'- Дата: {d:%d.%m.%Y}')
    for o, t in g:
        print(f'{t:%H:%M} - {o}')

'''
- Дата: 20.04.2022
15:14 - Покупка мяса
16:58 - Покупка техники
16:59 - Покупка машины
17:05 - Покупка кольца
22:20 - Покупка листа А4
- Дата: 21.04.2022
09:50 - Покупка товара
10:25 - Покупка подписки
12:13 - Покупка фена
15:58 - Покупка люстры
```